# Solving double summation in R studio without loops

Tags: r

[Double summation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xd9gL.png) 
Tried solve this double summation in R ( ∑10i=1∑5j=1(i^5(10+j^i) ) without using loops

in this way, but when solving it manually in hand I got a different answer - is this the correct way of solving such a problem?
Here I get the solution: 260.1827

```
 i <- seq(1, 10, 1) 
 j <- seq(1, 5, 1)
 denominators <- 10+j^i 
 fractions <- (i^5)/denominators
 sum(fractions)
```

[Possible solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mhKzg.png)

Comment: Can you please submit the code that you tried and its result and elaborate on what you expected in comparison to what you got as result?

Comment: I'm sorry, I added the code now :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using for loops:

```
sum = 0
for(i in 1:10){
  for(j in 1:5){
    sum = sum + i^5/(10+j^i)
  }
}
```

Result:

```
> sum
[1] 20845.76
```

Without loops:

```
i = rep(1:10, each=5)
j = rep(1:5, 10)
```

This way `i` and `j` looks like:

```
> i
 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5 5 6 6 6 6 6 7 7 7 7 7 8 8 8 8 8 9 9 9 9 9 10 10 10 10 10

> j
 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5 1  2  3  4  5
```

So every 5 `j`'s turns `i` up by one, then resets `j`.

```
sum(i^5/(10+j^i))
```

(Same result)

Comment: Thank you very much! Unfortunately I have to do it without using loops, which for me makes it pretty tricky

Comment: Thank you so much for your elaborate answer! It helped me make sense of the problem much more :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `expand.grid` and `apply`:

```
> sum(apply(expand.grid(i,j),1,function(v)v[1]^5/(10+v[2]^v[1])))
[1] 20845.76
```

Comment: Cleaner, but.... sure, but  using  `*apply` is just hiding the sum.  What I'd like to see is the conceptual equivalent of  `sum(over_x , sum(over_y , function(x,y))` so that fully compiled `sum` - like function can be used.

Answer (score 1):

First, define the inner sum as a function of i:

```
innerSum <- function(i) { 
  #The inner sum is a function of i, looping over each j from 1 to 5
  i^5 / (10+(1:5)^i)
}
```

Now, for every i from 1 to 10 you have to calculate this function and then add everything together. This can be done via `sapply`. This is a function that iterates over a collection-like datastructure (in our case the vector with the numbers for i), applies a function to every element and returns a vector with the function-results. The final step is to add everything together with `sum`:

```
sum(sapply(1:10, function(i) innerSum(i))) #returns 20845.76
```

Moreover, you can save some syntax. You could write

```
sum(sapply(1:10, innerSum)) #returns 20845.76
```

This is possible because the function `innerSum` only takes one argument and it is "clear for R", what to do. For more details, have a look at the documentation of `sapply` via calling `?sapply` in R-Studio.

Update:
With `sapply` you are using an implicit loop. So if you have to avoid loops, please mark Ricardos new answer as the accepted one. To be fair, mine is not correct therefore.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I played with it in R and it works very well , helped me make sense of this question :)

Comment: This is an elegant solution.

Comment: sure, but  using  `*apply` is just hiding the sum.  What I'd like to see is the conceptual equivalent of  `sum(over_x , sum(over_y , function(x,y))` so that fully compiled `sum` - like function can be used.